# Firefox: setTimeout chain causing lag and dropped browser events

Tags: javascript, firefox

If I have a page of just:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function doCycle() {
    setTimeout("doCycle();", 200);
  }
  doCycle();
</script>

<input></input>
```

When I open the page in Firefox on an older computer or have firebug open on a newer machine, the browser will randomly drop events (keyboard presses and clicks). For example, if I focus on an input element and then alternate key presses such as 'a' and 'b'. I will end up with output (in the input element) such as:

**ababababababababbababaababab**

where there are some repeated characters because certain keypresses were dropped. If I debug, no keydown or keypress events fired for the missed events. This also happens with buttons/clicks.

So my question is: Do you think it is a bug in firefox? or Why do you think it might be intended or inherent?

Don't know too much about how browsers handle setTimeout under the hood and can't find any other references to this issue on the web. Thought I would try to gather some more info here before opening a bug in the firefox bug tracker. Any thoughts or insights would be much appreciated!

Comment: Here's a great explanation of the javascript event loop and how async operations (like setTimeout) actually work in the browser: http://2014.jsconf.eu/speakers/philip-roberts-what-the-heck-is-the-event-loop-anyway.html

Comment: setTimeout is NOT asyncronous... do watch that video though, it's a very good description of the event loop.

Comment: Thank you both. That video was awesome!

One part I am still confused about is why the key/click events actually get dropped instead of just delayed until the callback queue function is done. If I am understanding from the video, those key/click events should get put into the callback queue and then get called once the setTimeout function is done and the call stack is clear again.

I also am curious why I can only produce this issue in firefox? Is it because firefox is slower and so the callback queue gets pulled from less frequently?

Again, any insight is super appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I dont get anything weird with that. The timeout will run after 200ms but it wont stop the browser from processing the code beneath it. Your question is not very clear though...

Comment: Hi Shakawkaw, sorry the question is unclear. Let me see if I can clear it up a bit:

I am experiencing an issue in firefox where, while I have 1 or more setTimeout loops going, the user/client occasionally loses (the browser doesn't acknowledge that they happened) keypresses and mouse clicks.


I have been observing/reproducing this by using an input html element and alternating pressing keys on the keyboard.

Comment: can you please make a fiddle with an example? I tried to replicate what you're saying without any luck